# Why does it take so long to load content when I click on 'Edit in SharePoint Designer'?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer

Whenever I click on 'site action' then 'Edit in SharePoint Designer', the content takes forever to load. Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

The most reason is this SharePoint designer architecture, that means it's based on SharePoint web service. When you working with SharePoint designer each action call HTTP Web Service that hosted on SharePoint.
for example at starting site collection will load on client.
Unfortunately there is any solution to speed up SharePoint designer.